# Can a ViewModel observe a parent ViewModel?

Tags: android, android-mvvm

Using Android MVVM architecture, can a ViewModel observe LiveData from a parent ViewModel ?

Comment: Use a repository instead of linking view-models.

Comment: @MartinZeitler When should I use repository and when should I use shared view model ?